# Using fewer mesh lines, 3D graphics

Tags: graphics3d, mesh, parametric-functions, stl-format

I want to make the Final use fewer mesh lines,
the ideal version will look like the second image.
Where the triangle shape is more clear and clean. Can anyone give me some advice on how to fix my code?

```
   ex1 = ParametricPlot3D[{(3 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], (3 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], 
       Sin[v]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
    
    
   mesh = Import[Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "ex1.stl", ex1]]
    
   edges = MeshPrimitives[mesh, 1]
    
   Final = Graphics3D[Map[Tube[#, .05] &, edges[[All, 1]]],Boxed -> False]
```

[image: First image]

[image: Second image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The FEM package will tend to give you more isotropic triangles as shown in your spherical mesh than other discretization functions in *Mathematica*.  Also, for a torus, an implicit region seems to give a cleaner mesh than a parametric region as can be seen by the [`FindMeshDefects`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMeshDefects.html) function.

Below, you can see a comparison between [`ParametricRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricRegion.html)and [`ImplicitRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html):

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
torus = ParametricRegion[{(3 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], (3 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], 
    Sin[v]}, {{u, 0, 2 π}, {v, 0, 2 π}}];
mrtorus = 
  MeshRegion@
   ToBoundaryMesh[torus, "MeshOrder" -> 1, MaxCellMeasure -> .1, 
    AccuracyGoal -> 1];
HighlightMesh[mrtorus, 1]
FindMeshDefects[mrtorus]
torus = SolidData["SolidTorus", "ImplicitRegion"][1, 3];
mrtorus = 
  MeshRegion@
   ToBoundaryMesh[torus, "MeshOrder" -> 1, MaxCellMeasure -> .1, 
    AccuracyGoal -> 1];
HighlightMesh[mrtorus, 1]
FindMeshDefects[mrtorus]
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to get edges less than 1616?`torus = SolidData["SolidTorus", "ImplicitRegion"][1, 3];
mrtorus = 
  MeshRegion@
   ToBoundaryMesh[torus, "MeshOrder" -> 1, MaxCellMeasure -> 1, 
    AccuracyGoal -> 1];`

Comment: @HyperGroups To have ultimate control over the number lines, you may have to resort to a structured mesh. The automatic mesh generators will probably add points to meet its internal requirements for a watertight mesh with triangles of sufficient quality.

Answer (score 4):

Change the `MeshFunctions` and `Mesh` and `PlotPoints`

```
ex1 = ParametricPlot3D[{(3 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], (3 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], 
    Sin[v]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, Boxed -> False, 
   Axes -> False, MeshFunctions -> Automatic, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
   PlotPoints -> {12, 8}];
reg = DiscretizeGraphics[ex1];
newedges = MeshPrimitives[reg, 1];
Graphics3D[Map[Tube[#, .05] &, newedges[[All, 1]]], Boxed -> False]
```

[image]